# Xuggler Live Video Streaming Example

Tags: java, live-streaming, xuggler

I downloaded Xuggler now and played a little bit around with it. Some examples work, others don't. There is no example of a video live stream with server and client in the demo files. Did anyone already establish a Xuggler Video Live Stream and can tell me how to do it or even post the server and client source code?

Answer (score 1):

You may be better off with something like ffmpeg using javacv like this fellow http://www.walking-productions.com/notslop/2013/01/16/android-live-streaming-courtesy-of-javacv-and-ffmpeg/ .

Xuggler is no longer actively developed , and while it was good at the time it hasn't kept up wih ffmpeg API updates.